# How To Fork Create React App For Custom Builds

Tags: reactjs, facebook, create-react-app

I've been doing a lot of react development with my own custom build setup with webpack. As my projects grow the build become slower and I'm not always able to tweak my builds to be more performant. Also having all my dev dependencies live within the project can become messy and distracting. I've always loved create react app for it ease of use, performance, and community. I recently forked the repo and created my own custom react-script and have enjoyed the minimalism  of my packages only focusing on dependencies. I want to customize scripts more, adding new ones that analyze code or optimize assets. I have some knowledge of node and processes but not enough to full comfortable tweaking chunks of code.

It would be awesome if anyone could recommend articles or lectures that pertain specifically to destructuring create react app or/and working with node cli code. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

react-app-rewired could give you a better understanding of the CRA

https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired

You can use rescripts for advance CRA Config, go through the readme.

https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts

Answer (score 0):

[crisp-react](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-react) is a boilerplate project that consists of a sample React app with multiple SPAs and optimized script bundles coupled with an Express backend. On conrary to CRA the project does not use react-scripts under the hood. The client and backend are separated into independent subprojects you can build, run, debug, test and lint. Maybe the client can meet your needs.